# howto handle on:click in a custom svelte-magnifier component

Tags: image, onclick, svelte

I'm using [this component](https://github.com/ambarvm/svelte-magnifier) to magnify the area of an image under the mouse.

The doc says that unhandled props should be passed to the underlying `<img>` but in my example (below) `handleClick` only works with the img, the Magnifier seems to swallow the event

Run [the example in the svelte repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/7e883e01317a45d09d97125d684d9741?version=3.58.0)

```
<script>
    import { Magnifier } from 'svelte-magnifier';
    
    let imageUrl = "https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/OYQvquvaVWpu.jpg?o=1"
    
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    
    function handleClick(event) {
        x = event.offsetX;
        y = event.offsetY;
    }
    
</script>

<Magnifier src={imageUrl} width="500px" on:click={handleClick} />

<div class="coordinates">You clicked at ({x}, {y})</div>

<img src={imageUrl} width="500px" on:click={handleClick}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are separate from events and the component provides no `click` event. It does not provide any events for that matter, none are forwarded or dispatched (see [source](https://github.com/ambarvm/svelte-magnifier/blob/main/src/lib/Magnifier.svelte)).

Your best bet would be to wrap the component in a regular DOM element and handle the event there.